# How to write each row or observation out as an individual file in R

Tags: r, subset

I need to write each row out as a csv. 
Example data:

```
myData <- structure(list(SID = c(200101L, 200102L, 200201L, 200202L, 200203L
), pr_1979_01_01 = c(11.0536289215088, 11.0536289215088, 7.78615140914917, 
7.78615140914917, 7.78615140914917), pr_1979_01_02 = c(10.554141998291, 
10.554141998291, 11.3847818374634, 11.3847818374634, 11.3847818374634
), pr_1979_01_03 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pr_1979_01_04 = c(0.453366577625275, 
0.453366577625275, 0.38262751698494, 0.38262751698494, 0.38262751698494
)), .Names = c("SID", "pr_1979_01_01", "pr_1979_01_02", "pr_1979_01_03", 
"pr_1979_01_04"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I know I can use `subset()` or `dplyr::filter()`, but I have several hundred rows and thousands of columns. How can I automate this?

Comment: Why do you need to write a single row as  csv file?  Try `lapply(seq_len(nrow(myData)), function(i) write.csv(myData[i,], paste0('file', i, '.csv'), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))`

Comment: Each 'observation' here is a study site. I need to create weather files to be read into a model. Each site needs a specific weather file. I also have maximum temperature, minimum temperature, etc. that will be joined by site ID.

Comment: Please check the edited comment above with the code.

Comment: looks like it worked. thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the sequence of rows of the dataset using `lapply`, subset the rows of the dataset and then use `write.csv` on each row

```
 lapply(seq_len(nrow(myData)), function(i) 
     write.csv(myData[i,], paste0('SID', i, '.csv'), 
            row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))
```

**Edit**

To write the files with the name from a column, such as the site ID, create a vector of said column.

```
SID <- myData$SID
```

then use the following:

```
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(myData)), function(i) 
  write.csv(myData[i,], paste0(SID[i], '.csv'), 
            row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))
```

note the differences in the paste arguments:

```
paste0(SID[i], i, '.csv')
```

vs

`paste0(SID[i], '.csv')`

Comment: can we paste the SID into the filename, instead of generic filename?

Comment: @SoilSciGuy  Just change the `file` by `SID` (updated the post)

Comment: That simply pastes 'SID1', 'SID2'. I tried to create a vector from the SID column, and then use that to paste in, but still not working.

Comment: Essentially, I need the filename to correspond to the SID column.

Comment: @SoilSciGuy In the case use `paste0(SID[i], i, '.csv')`